# How to find a coordinate by connecting the three coordinates lie on three sides of an equilateral triangle using HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Let's suppose i have an equilateral triangle abc having three coordinates A(40,60), B(70,30), C(50,80) as shown in figure. 
[Triangle with it's Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/layfm.png)

I want to find a coordinate which intersects with all the point let this coordinate be D(x,y) as shown in figure:
[Intersected Coordinate D with other Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKqBP.png)

Given that AD is parallel to bc, BD is parallel to ab, and DC is parallel to ac. Please help in finding coordinate D.
Until now I am able to locate the three points on the triangle using HTML canvas but not able to connect all the coordinates to form D coordinate.
All coordinates are the pixel values.
For making a triangle:

```
var v0={x:114,y:366};
var v1={x:306,y:30};
var v2={x:498,y:366};
var triangle=[v0,v1,v2];
drawTriangle(triangle);

function drawTriangle(t){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(t[0].x,t[0].y);
ctx.lineTo(t[1].x,t[1].y);
ctx.lineTo(t[2].x,t[2].y);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle='black';
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.stroke();
}
```

Function to draw coordinates on Triangle.
The x,y coordinates are taken randomly.

```
function drawCoordinates(x,y){
ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // Red color
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
//For Drwaing Cords
//drawCords(x,y);
}
```

Is there any way to connect these three Points to form D by satisfying this parallel conditions. Please help. Also kindly suggest if you need any further clarification, I am new to this HTML canvas technology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's math

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a little bit different:

1. I draw the triangle
2. I draw 2 lines paraleles with 2 sides of the triangle
3. I calculate the points to draw a third line paralele with the third side of the triangle.

If you know the points for the 3 lines you need to calculate only the intersection of 2 of them.

To calculate the intersection I'm using http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width = 600;
var ch = canvas.height = 400;



// triangle
var v0={x:114,y:366};
var v1={x:306,y:30};
var v2={x:498,y:366};


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(v0.x,v0.y);
ctx.lineTo(v1.x,v1.y);
ctx.lineTo(v2.x,v2.y);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

//lines
var p1 = {x:40,y:300};
var p2 = {x:500,y:300};
var p3 = {x:356,y:30};
var p4 = {x:164,y:366};

// draw the first 2 lines
drawLine(p1,p2);
drawLine(p3,p4);



// find the intersection between the 2 lines

function Intersect(p1,p2,p3,p4){
  var denominator = (p4.y - p3.y)*(p2.x - p1.x) - (p4.x - p3.x)*(p2.y - p1.y);
  var ua = ((p4.x - p3.x)*(p1.y - p3.y) - (p4.y - p3.y)*(p1.x - p3.x))/denominator;
  var ub = ((p2.x - p1.x)*(p1.y - p3.y) - (p2.y - p1.y)*(p1.x - p3.x))/denominator;
  var x = p1.x + ua*(p2.x - p1.x);
  var y = p1.y + ua*(p2.y - p1.y);
  if(ua > 0 && ua < 1 && ub > 0  && ub < 1){
  return {x:x,y:y};
  }else{return false;}
}

var o = Intersect(p1,p2,p3,p4);

// draw the point of intersection
  if(o){  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(o.x, o.y,3,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  }


// calculate the position of the 3-rd line
var p5 = {x:o.x+100/Math.tan(Math.PI/3),y:o.y+100};
var p6 = {x:o.x-100/Math.tan(Math.PI/3),y:o.y-100}

drawLine(p5,p6);

function drawLine(p1,p2){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got one answer, that if I have any point on one side of an equilateral triangle we can find it's parallel coordinates on other sides of triangle by using (x+l*cos(@),y+l*sin(@)) and thereafter we get two lines using the end coordinates of two lines can find the intersection points by solving simple line equation and thereafter connecting all the three points i,e A(40,60), B(70,30), C(50,80) with the intersection point D(X,Y). To find the intersection i have used this function:

```
function checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
// if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contains the point
var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
  x: null,
  y: null,
  onLine1: false,
  onLine2: false
};
denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
if (denominator == 0) {
  return result;
}
a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
a = numerator1 / denominator;
b = numerator2 / denominator;

// if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
/*
        // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
        x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
        y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));
        */
// if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
  result.onLine1 = true;
}
// if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
  result.onLine2 = true;
}
// if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
return result;
```

}

The result holds the x,y coordinates and therefore using drawCoordinates(x,y) function i can draw the resulting triangle.
This solved my problem. Thank you for all the feedbacks and help.